# javascript to enable and disable a button based on changes in form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, bootstrap-4

i am using a javscript to enable a button based on the changes in the form field in django python using bootstrap.below is the script

```
$("#employee_name, #employee_name2").on("keyup",function() {
  $(".btn-action").prop("disabled",false);
  if( ($("#employee_name").val()) == ($("#employee_name2").val())) {
     $(".btn-action").prop("disabled",true);
  }
});
```

also the below code in html to initially disable button

```HTML
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 btn-action" disabled>Save</button>
```

but the button stays disabled even after changing values in the field.any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems like functionality you can skip to get on with the rest of your code design. Working on "little problems" is indication of procrastination on bigger problems.

Comment: you are right.i  usually work on the designing stuff when i am not in the mood. today is one such day.

Comment: Happens to me alot too. Since you are using jquery, I guess it would help to see your relevant html or an explanation from you on how `#employee_name` differs from `#employee_name2`? Your html or further explanations on what *you want to do* will help in anyone (including you) on solving the logical error.

Comment: #employee_name is the original value in the employee name placeholder in the html form.#employee_name 2 is like a temporary variable to hold the current employee name in the html form.basically its to compare if there is any change in the employe name while editing the employee details.based on the detected changes the save button should become active or remain disabled if no changes. below is the link to view my github edit_toners_form and edit_tonerdetails_from are the html which is inside the toners app https://github.com/muneermohd9690/sent-receive-project

Comment: Ok so you combine new employee with edit employee in same form? This makes sense but backend must be able to differentiate between new and existing,

Comment: i am using jquery to do that.if the values are not same then the button will become active. or else remain disabled.

Comment: i have found the answer i need to write the below script '$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#employee_name,#employee_name2").on("keyup",function(){
        $(".btn-action2").prop("disabled",false);
            if(($("#employee_name").val())==($("#employee_name2").val())){
                    $(".btn-action2").prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
   });'                                     and below in the html                                                                                   
  'button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3 btn-action2" disabled>Save</button>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the below script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#employee_name,#employee_name2").on("keyup",function(){
    $(".btn-action2").prop("disabled",false);
        if(($("#employee_name").val())==($("#employee_name2").val())){
                $(".btn-action2").prop("disabled",true);
    }
});
```

});
and below in the html

```
button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-3 btn-action2" disabled>Save</button>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).